# What is the reason for the use of different voices for the perfect in Mark 1:15?

Tags: greek, grammar, mark

Hi in the following verse:

Mark 1:15 (UBS5): **Πεπλήρωται** ὁ καιρὸς καὶ **ἤγγικεν** ἡ βασιλεία τοῦ θεοῦ· μετανοεῖτε καὶ πιστεύετε ἐν τῷ εὐαγγελίῳ.

> ... **has been fulfilled** the time and **has drawn near** the kingdom of God

> [Literal interlinear from EGNT]

What is the purpose of the author in using the perfect passive for Πεπλήρωται  and perfect active for ἤγγικεν? For instance, the perfect passive could have been used for both or the perfect active.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The two verbs have different subjects.

Comment: I have edited only to make it clear to all users what is being asked. (Up-voted +1.)

Comment: Thanks Nigel J appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English Standard Version

> and saying, “The **time** is fulfilled

is fulfilled,
Πεπλήρωται (Peplērōtai)
Verb - Perfect Indicative Middle or **Passive** - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's Greek 4137: From pleres; to make replete, i.e. to cram, level up, or to furnish, satisfy, execute, finish, verify, etc.

Time is not the actor; God is.

New Living Translation

> “The time promised **by God** has come at last!”

New Living Translation

> “The Kingdom of God is near!

is near
ἤγγικεν (ēngiken)
Verb - Perfect Indicative **Active** - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's Greek 1448: Trans: I bring near; intrans: I come near, approach. From eggus; to make near, i.e. approach.

Kingdom of God is the actor. It has come near. It makes no sense to make it passive: the Kingdom of God has been come near.

Comment: Thanks Tony very helpful and clear and inline with how I understood subject/object in respect to passive/active. Ι guess I was curious as to why the author (or Jesus) chose not to word this differently where the actor (subject) is God an the the verb relating to fulfilment is active and wondered if there was anything more behind it e.g. KoG - it could also be “the kingdom of God has been brought near” (i.e. God is the actor and the coming near is passive).

Comment: Glad I could help. Partly, it is due to the idiomatic usage of the Greek word for fulfilled which is almost always used as passive. These are more pragmatic issues than syntax. Ultimately, it was just Mark's writing style.

Comment: Okay great thats the exact thing I wanted to understand - so its idiomatic/writing style.

Comment: God bless your reading :)